# What is it being called to load data from another machine from remote server

Tags: php, web-services, rpc

In programming, server-side programming code/script (ex. PHP) during execution will use either 'curl' library or 'file_get_contents' load remote data from remote machine. What is this mechanism being called in the 'web development'/'web programming' domain?

Is there a way to call this method? Comparing to other methods like loading data from a local file ( still on the server side). And loading data from remote server though AJAX( client side).

Comment: Can you be more elaborate on this ??

Comment: yes. just want to be a bit more strict about the naming of this.

Comment: The first term that comes to mind is **cross site request**.